# streamR package dataframe not showing all tweets

Tags: r, twitter

I am running the following query in R to get 24hrs of tweets from the streaming API (OAuth details are in a separate file that I am calling):

```
library(streamR)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(stringr)
load("my_oauth.Rdata")
filterStream(file.name = "tweets.json", track = c("@Sydney_Uni", "usyd", "syd uni", "sydney uni", "university of sydney" ), language = "en", timeout = 86400, oauth = my_oauth)
tweets.df <- parseTweets("tweets.json", simplify = FALSE)
```

This results in the following

> Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 86400 seconds with up to 1993 tweets downloaded.

However, I only get some tweets parsed to my dataframe

> 145 tweets have been parsed.

Why don't all the tweets that have been downloaded get parsed to the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the **documentation** for `ParseTweets()`.

Do the following in your R console:

```
?ParseTweets()
```

You will find the following info in the help section:

> The total number of tweets that are parsed might be lower than the
>   number of lines in the file or object that contains the tweets because
>   blank lines, deletion notices, and incomplete tweets are ignored.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. What I get in my dad is only <10% of tweets downloaded. That seems like a lot of deletions, incomplete etc. Any additional explanations?

Comment: @user1222447 This is what I have found: Open the JSON file using a text editor, and try to see how many tweets have actually been downloaded. Most of the times what `ParseTweets()` show is the actual number of tweets downloaded.